# Play *.caf files (iOS/Apple) under Java

Tags: java, ios, javasound, caf

I have two applications, the first one is iOS application that record sound and save it in `*.caf` files. the second one is Java application that need to read this `*.caf` sound files and to play them.

I looking for *Java code* that can read/play these `*.caf` sound files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe the short answer is there isn't any. At least not any free code that I could find at the moment (I conducted a relatively extensive search recently for free SPIs and turned up all sorts, such as `APE` - but nothing for `caf`.) JavaFX, the other potential candidate for Java media, doesn't currently support it either:

> Audio: MP3; AIFF containing uncompressed PCM; WAV containing uncompressed PCM; MPEG-4 multimedia container with Advanced Audio Coding (AAC) audio

I would suggest your best option, short of implementing this yourself, would be one of two options:

- Alter your other application so that it saved in a more widely accepted file type - there are others out there that can do lossless audio rather well, such as FLAC, which [does have an SPI](http://jflac.sourceforge.net/). Alternatively, use WAV or AIFF (or just mp3 if you're happy with a lossy format.)
- Use a native library to play back the caf file for each platform you wish to support, and use JNI / JNA to go between Java and native code.

Comment: OK, so why not use something like mp3? Something has to give here, exactly what is best depends on your use case, which I don't know about...